# change permission on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

hy folks

To connect to kubernetes I have to enter my token once connected I can do everything.
only here I just realized that if I click on skipe on the kubernetes connection interface 
I am connected and I can do everything too.

I don't really know where to look to fix the problem. From what I read, I have to look at kube-system and RBAC.

can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide full error log here? Also, add step-by-step procedure if possible

Comment: As a side note, on GKE, Kubernetes Dashobars is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards).

Answer (score 0):

i find a temporary solution. to remove the skip buttom on the dashboard page login . 
later i will try to find how to do that properly with **RBAC**

i've set up the params `- --disable-skip=true`
unfortunatelly whithout success  and i dont understand why  :(

[kubernetes-dashboard-deployment.yaml][https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/ade49c2df5b6c9c2b6c076373eef3661]